# how to create own vscode dev container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I want to run my go project with old Golang version 1.12 in VS Code container. But currently, no dev container with old go version is available in Microsoft docker registry.
so how can I create my own docker container with given base Ubuntu version, old go version and other tool chains? And how should I push this new container in docker registry?

Comment: [Build from source](https://go.dev/doc/install/source)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit? How?